# Breakings URLs with biblatex

Tags: biblatex, line-breaking, urls

I know that `biblatex` offers various options to tune the breaking of URLs in the bibliography, but in the following example nothing seems to work:

```
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
    @book{Voigt.A:1906a,
        Address = {Leipzig},
        Author = {Voigt, Andreas},
        Publisher = {Göschen'sche Verlagshandlung},
        Subtitle = {Dreihundert Vorträge},
        Title = {Die Sozialen Utopien},
        Url = {http://www.archive.org/details/diesozialenutop00voiggoog},
        Urldate = {2011-10-29},
        Year = {1906}
    }
    }
    \end{filecontents}
    \documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
    \setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{10000}
    \setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{10000}
    \setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{10000}
    \begin{document}
    \cite{Voigt.A:1906a}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

I set all the relevant counters to their maximum, but this doesn't influence the result. Interesting detail: when I set `fontsize` to 13, it breaks the URL.

Comment: But where should it break the url. It is not allowed to break it at `diesozialenutop00voiggoog`, if you add `\sloppy` before `\printbibliography` you'll see that it can break it, at the cost of stretching.

Comment: I definitely would prefer it to break after `details` than the current result. In my original document, the bibliography is printed raggedright anyway.

Comment: You should not change your question in a way that invalidates current and correct answers. You should instead open a new question, linked to this one, with the different setup. I rolled back to the previous question. Anyway, your setting of `\bibsetup` is wrong as it doesn't include `\biburlsetup` like the original `\bibsetup` command; doing `\appto\bibsetup{\RaggedRight}` seems better.

Comment: Your MWE does not even compile after your recent edit. Please do not change the question again. You have already gotten a work-around for your problem in the comments. If you want other people to benefit from that, ask a new question with the appropriate explanation, so it can be found by searching. I will roll back your edit again.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A penalty of 10000 *forbids* breaks. Set the penalties to smaller values:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=12pt,paper=a4,]{scrartcl}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
    \usepackage{biblatex}
    \addbibresource{bib.bib}
    \setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{100}
    \setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{100}
    \setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{100}
    \begin{document}
    \cite{Voigt.A:1906a}
    \printbibliography
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: O man, that was really stupid of me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Mmh, not so easy after all. While this works in the MWE, I use `\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\RaggedRight}` in my original document. `RaggedRight` seems to turn this off completely. While I understand that ragged text should be more tolerant about breaking lines, this behavior doesn't seem optimal.

Comment: I updated the example.

Comment: You removed `\biburlsetup`, use `\renewcommand{\bibsetup}{\biburlsetup\RaggedRight}`, or better `\appto{\bibsetup}{\RaggedRight}`