# Breaking URLs in biblatex

Tags: biblatex, url

I need help as I can't find a way to break long URLs exactly where I want. I work on Sharelatex (as I can't install LaTeX distribution on my office computer), and I was using `\bibliography` until now but it doesn't work any more. So I added `biblatex` package which seems to work pretty well.

However, `\def\UrlBreaks` doesn't work any more either... I tried the solution given [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/264122/breakings-urls-with-biblatex), in vain... It breaks URLs only at "-"...
The idea would be to break URLs at `/`, `_`, `=`, `?`...

If it can help, my preamble looks like this:

## Preamble

```
\documentclass[11pt,frenchb,fleqn,reqno]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                    
\usepackage{ae,lmodern}                         
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                        

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}

\makeatletter 
\long\def\@makefntextFB#1{%
    \ifx\thefootnote\ftnISsymbol
        \@makefntextORI{#1}%
    \else
        \rule\z@\footnotesep
        \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\@thefnmark}%
            \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\z@
                \kern2em\llap{\@thefnmark.\kern0.5em}%
            \fi
        \hangindent2em\hangafter\@ne#1
    \fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\twobar}{/\kern-0.2em/}             
\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref}           
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\ttfamily\footnotesize}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-\do?\do\_}             

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}                     
\usepackage{array}                             

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\pc}[1]{\SI{#1}{\percent}}          
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}                   
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}                

\usepackage{graphicx}                           
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{frenchb.ldf}{Figure}             

\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}   
\tolerance 400                                 
\pretolerance 200

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{frenchb}{french}
\addbibresource{biblio.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9999}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9999}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{9999}

\usepackage{babel}
```

## In document

```
\begin{document}

Bla bla bla \cite{obs}.
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Références}
\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

## Bib file

```
@misc{obs,
      title = "Titre", 
      url = {https://www.reallylongurl.fr/aaaa/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb/ccccccc-ccccc_ddddddddd?eeeeeeeeee=125784.pdf}
}
```

Here is what I get in my bibliography: 
[image]

I hope someone has a great idea to solve this!
Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your sample LaTeX document doesn't contain any `\cite`-type instructions and hence won't create any formatted bib entries. Please edit your posting to make it generate the issue you're trying to fix.

Comment: Thanks ! I added a `\cite` in my example. However, I don't know yet how to show the result here...

Comment: Done. Hope it's good like this ;)

Comment: For sure, `url` should be loaded before, not after, `hyperref`. If I make the appropriate change, I am unable to reproduce the output shown in your screenshot. Instead, I get a linebreak between `ccccccc` and `-ccccc`. Not perfect by any means, but nowhere near as bad as what's in your screenshot.

Comment: I loaded `url` before `hyperref`, I get the same output... However, that's pretty surprising that I don't get the break at `-ccccc` as it's the only break that works for my other links...

Comment: How do you compile?

Answer (score 2):

Well, I created a MWE from your codes, and compiled with `pdflatex`.

The main problem in your code is that package `hyperref` should be called as **last one** in your case.

Please see the following MWE (I marked my code changes with `<======`)

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@misc{obs,
  title = "Titre", 
  url = {https://www.reallylongurl.fr/aaaa/bbbbbbbbbbbbbbbbb/ccccccc-ccccc_ddddddddd?eeeeeeeeee=125784.pdf}
}
\end{filecontents}


\documentclass[11pt,frenchb,fleqn,reqno]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ae,lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{babel} % <==================================================
\usepackage{showframe} % <==============================================

\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.2}

\makeatletter 
\long\def\@makefntextFB#1{%
    \ifx\thefootnote\ftnISsymbol
        \@makefntextORI{#1}%
    \else
        \rule\z@\footnotesep
        \setbox\@tempboxa\hbox{\@thefnmark}%
            \ifdim\wd\@tempboxa>\z@
                \kern2em\llap{\@thefnmark.\kern0.5em}%
            \fi
        \hangindent2em\hangafter\@ne#1
    \fi}
\makeatother

\newcommand{\twobar}{/\kern-0.2em/}             

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}                     
\usepackage{array}                             

\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[output-decimal-marker={,}]{siunitx}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcommand{\pc}[1]{\SI{#1}{\percent}}          
\usepackage{amssymb, amsmath}                   
\setlength{\mathindent}{0cm}                

\usepackage{graphicx}                           
\usepackage{silence}
\WarningFilter{frenchb.ldf}{Figure}             

%\usepackage[dvipsnames]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.15}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\apptocmd{\sloppy}{\hbadness 10000\relax}{}{}   
\tolerance 400                                 
\pretolerance 200

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{14pt}

\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=numeric,sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{frenchb}{french}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\usepackage{url}
\setcounter{biburllcpenalty}{9999}
\setcounter{biburlucpenalty}{9999}
\setcounter{biburlnumpenalty}{9999}

\usepackage[breaklinks=true]{hyperref} % <==============================
\renewcommand{\UrlFont}{\ttfamily\footnotesize}
\def\UrlBreaks{\do\/\do-\do?\do\_}             


\begin{document}

Bla bla bla \cite{obs}.
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Références}
\printbibliography{}
\end{document}
```

and you get the wished result:

[image: resulting pdf]